# Декоратор в unity на примере вооружения космического корабля

Tags: c#, unity3d, шаблоны

В игре вооружение имеет 3 режима: одиночный выстрел, двойной выстрел и тройной выстрел. Также вооружение может быть разного типа (ионное, лазер, плазма). Соответственно разные типы орудий должны иметь один из этих режимов. По умолчанию игрок имеет одиночный режим оружия и ионный тип орудия. В процессе игры игрок подбирает итемы (бонусы), которые должны менять или тип орудия или его режим (зависит от бонуса).

В процессе решения задачи я изучал паттерн Декоратор и понял, что он как раз подойдет к этой задачи (наверно). Вот UML диаграмма (не полная, но суть понятна думаю)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Attacker (режим) - компонент, который спавнит пули с определенным аттакспидом.
AttackerDecorator (тип орудия) - компонент, который должен менять состояние (пули, аттакспид) Attacker'а
Что-то типо такого - `new IonAttacker(new DoubleAttacker());`
С реализацией режимов проблем не возникло, а вот реализовать декораторы не смог). Точнее не совсем понимаю как это сделать, просто attacker это MonoBehaviour и как реализовать это `new IonAttacker(new DoubleAttacker());` не совсем понятно для меня. При этом еще должна быть возможность менять как тип так и режим.

Код Attacker'ов:

```
namespace Core.WeaponComponents
{
    public class Attacker : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private GameObject _bulletPrefab;
        [SerializeField]
        private float _attackSpeed;

        protected Transform _transform;

        protected float AttackSpeedTimer { get; private set; }

        protected GameObject BulletPrefab { get { return _bulletPrefab; } }

        private void Awake()
        {
            _transform = this.transform;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            Attack();
        }

        private void Attack()
        {
            IncreaseAttackSpeedTimer();
            SpawnBullets();
        }

        protected virtual void IncreaseAttackSpeedTimer()
        {
            AttackSpeedTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (AttackSpeedTimer >= this._attackSpeed)
            {
                AttackSpeedTimer = 0f;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void SpawnBullets()
        {
            if (AttackSpeedTimer == 0)
            {
                LeanPool.Spawn(_bulletPrefab, _transform.position, _transform.rotation);
            }
        }
    }
}  


namespace Core.WeaponComponents
{
    public class DoubleAttacker : Attacker
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private float offset;

        protected sealed override void SpawnBullets()
        {
            if (base.AttackSpeedTimer == 0)
            {
                Vector2 leftBulletPosition = new Vector2
                (base._transform.position.x - offset, base._transform.position.y);
                Vector2 rightBulletPosition = new Vector2
                    (base._transform.position.x + offset, base._transform.position.y);

                LeanPool.Spawn(base.BulletPrefab, leftBulletPosition, base._transform.rotation);
                LeanPool.Spawn(base.BulletPrefab, rightBulletPosition, base._transform.rotation);
            }
        }
    }
}  


namespace Core.WeaponComponents
{
    public abstract class AttackerDecorator : Attacker
    {
        public Attacker Attacker { get; set; }
    }
}  


namespace Core.WeaponComponents
{
    public class IonAttacker : AttackerDecorator
    {
        //???
    }
}
```

Comment: мне кажется тут лучше подойдет Стратегия. В типы оружия вы передаете типы атаки (ионная и тд)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно даже стратегия лучше подойдёт что б задавать типы стрельбы для оружия. И эти типы стрельбы будут работать с общим интерфейсом режимов стрельбы. Возможно так будет лучше, но тут ещё нужно разбираться.